# initialize chef attribute with ruby block?

Tags: ruby, variables, attributes, chef-infra

Here's the ruby command I'd like to save the output of `Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')` I was thinking I could just add something like this to my recipe '

```
TODAY={ ::Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M') }
```

but this doesn't seem to work

```
==> default: [2015-04-10T17:53:44+00:00] ERROR: /tmp/vagrant-chef/eb36617d9c55f20fcee6cd316a379482/cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/install_app.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
    ==> default: TODAY={ (Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')) }
    ==> default:                                             ^
    ==> default: [2015-04-10T17:53:44+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

eventually I want to make this an attribute so I can access it from multiple recipes

```
default['neustar-npac-deployment']['node_ohai_time'] = TODAY={ ::Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M') }
```

thanks!

Comment: Why do you have the `{}` this is not a block but actually Hash literal syntax. if you want this to be a lazy block use `->{}` or `lambda {}` which will both produce a `lambda` or `Proc.new {}` which will produce a true `Proc`. so something like `TODAY = -> {Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')}`. Then to get the result it would be `TODAY.call` or you could just set it directly as `TODAY = Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')` but it seemed you wanted it to be lazy evaluated so a lambda might fit best.

Comment: I don't mind if it is lazy evaluated,  I was just following an example without understanding what the `{ }` are for.  I'll try to use it directly the  and see if it does the trick.  Thanks

Comment: My point was `TODAY = Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')` means `TODAY` will not change once it is evaluated because it is a fixed constant where as `TODAY = -> { Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M') }` means every time you use `TODAY.call` it will evaluate the lambda and return the response current as of right now. Does that make sense?

Comment: oh I  understand now, that's pretty neat! In this case I just need it to be constant but I'll have it in mind for future reference.

Comment: you should post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your request I am posting this as an answer.

Right now you are using `{}` incorrectly as this is not a block but a `Hash` literal which is why it is complaining. In order to make this a block you must use a `lambda` or `Proc` object.

**lambda**

lambda's can be created using one of 2 different syntax styles

```
-> { "This is a lambda" } 
#=> #<Proc:0x2a954c0@(irb):1 (lambda)>
lambda { "This is also a lambda" }
#=> #<Proc:0x27337c8@(irb):2 (lambda)>
```

Either way is perfectly acceptable

**Proc**

Procs can be created using `Proc.new { "This is a proc" }`

for this question the semantic differences are not needed.

`lambda` and `Proc` will lazy evaluate the statement inside the block on `#call` which means that the value can remain fluid.

Let's take your example:

```
 NOW = Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')
 # in this case NOW will be evaluated once and will always equal the 
 # string result of when it was first interpretted
 TODAY = -> {Time.now.strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')}
 # in this case TODAY is simply a lambda and it's value will be dependent
 # upon the time when you "call" it so something like this will clearly illustrate
 # the difference
 while NOW == TODAY.call
    puts "Still the same time" 
 end 
 # after this NOW will still reflect it's initial set value and for 
 # a while ~ 1 minute this will output "Still the same time" 
 # at some point TODAY.call will increment up by 1 minute because it is 
 # re-evaluated on each `#call` thus allowing it to change periodically with the clock
```

I hope this in some way helps you better understand the concept.

Comment: thanks for the great introduction into proc and lambda!